# Can a command on SSH window change title (Ubuntu and PuTTY)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

Is it possible for a command  to change the title displayed on a SSH window

- server Ubuntu
- client PuTTY on windows Vista

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo -en '\033];Hello World\007'
```

Comment: That works fine - thanks.  I was foled initially but then released that the command prompt was also setting the title.   If you excute your command then a long running command (wich is what I want to do) it is fine.